# mysql combine every rows in group by

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
id   weekday   money   rank
---------------------------
1    0         20      1
2    1         30      1
3    2         40      1
4    3         50      1
5    4         60      1
6    5         70      1
7    6         80      1
```

I want to get this result:

```
rank   Sun   Mon   Tue   Wed   Thu   Fri   Sat
----------------------------------------------
1      20    30    40    50    60    70    80
```

My query so far:

```
SELECT rank,
    CASE WHEN weekday = 0 THEN money END AS 'Sun',
    CASE WHEN weekday = 1 THEN money END AS 'Mon',
    CASE WHEN weekday = 2 THEN money END AS 'Tue',
    CASE WHEN weekday = 3 THEN money END AS 'Wed',
    CASE WHEN weekday = 4 THEN money END AS 'Thu',
    CASE WHEN weekday = 5 THEN money END AS 'Fri',
    CASE WHEN weekday = 6 THEN money END AS 'Sat'
FROM weekday
GROUP BY rank
```

This query only shows sun money. How can I modify the MySQL query to get the required result?

Comment: What query have you tried so far?

Comment: SELECT rank,
 CASE WHEN weekday = 0 THEN money END AS 'Sun',
 CASE WHEN weekday = 1 THEN money END AS 'Mon',
 CASE WHEN weekday = 2 THEN money END AS 'Tue',
 CASE WHEN weekday = 3 THEN money END AS 'Wed',
 CASE WHEN weekday = 4 THEN money END AS 'Thu',
 CASE WHEN weekday = 5 THEN money END AS 'Fri',
 CASE WHEN weekday = 6 THEN money END AS 'Sat'
FROM
 `weekday`
GROUP BY
 rank

This only show sun money

Comment: You'll need to edit your question and add the query there so its formatted and clear for others to see as well.

Comment: OK,Thanks,This is my first question.I don't know how to formatted my word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check it :

```
select rank,sum(sun) as sun, 
        sum(mon) as Mon,sum(tue) as tue, 
        sum(wed) as wed, sum(thu) as thu ,
        sum(fri) as Fri, sum(sat) as sat 
    from 
        (SELECT rank, 
            CASE WHEN weekday = 0 THEN money END AS 'Sun', 
            CASE WHEN weekday = 1 THEN money END AS 'Mon', 
            CASE WHEN weekday = 2 THEN money END AS 'Tue', 
            CASE WHEN weekday = 3 THEN money END AS 'Wed', 
            CASE WHEN weekday = 4 THEN money END AS 'Thu', 
            CASE WHEN weekday = 5 THEN money END AS 'Fri', 
            CASE WHEN weekday = 6 THEN money END AS 'Sat' 
        FROM weekday where rank =1) 
    as Tbl2
    group by rank
```